# Recommendations for eval on save workflow for projects?

Tags: hooks, projectile, package-development, eval

I've started to write a package and excessive use of the interactive `eval-*` functions has become a pain point for me.

After I make a change re-evaluating entire file or package is almost always appropriate.  `eval-buffer` is usually sufficient and usually what I run.

Since I'm an emacser with the *C-x C-s Tourette-esque tic* eval'ing the buffer would be something I'd like to happen automatically on save.  I'm writing elisp, but I can imagine other circumstances where the same workflow would be useful.  Eval'ing the entire project (i.e. `(require 'my-package)`) would often also be sufficient in cases that the package is in `load-path`.

I've started to use .dir-locals.el files in these projects which add a buffer-local `after-save-hook`:

```
((emacs-lisp-mode
   (eval add-hook 'before-save-hook 'eval-buffer nil t)))
```

What would be a better way to accommodate this sort of workflow / What other ways have people implemented this workflow?

I'm wishing there's something in the realm of zero-configuration "Do what I mean" to figure out / track which projects/directories/files I want eval'd on save and do it.  I happen to use projectile, but am still curious about broader possibilities which may or may not be usable with projectile.

A few thoughts:

- [projectile-load-settings](https://github.com/jfeltz/projectile-load-settings)
- global hook conditioned on a file ("Cask"?) existing in the project root

Comment: If you're hitting `C-x C-s` constantly, surely auto-`eval`-on-save is a *really bad* idea? You want to eval when the code is *good*, not just whenever an instinctive habit kicks in.

Comment: @phils Not a concern.  My code is always correct.  Backspace and delete are  remapped as additional modifiers.